# i cannot be a message whether it is succesfully logged in or not

Tags: android

```
 EditText txtUserName;
 EditText txtPassword;
 Button btnLogin;
 Button btnCancel;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);


     txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
     txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
     btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

           Button  btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
         btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
                     Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else{
                     Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                     }
                       }
                          });

           Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
           next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

                public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddName.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
            }});

       }

 }
```

while running this app on emulator it runs fine without any errors but **it doesnt show any message that username and password are succesfully logged or a invalid login** but when i click on next button the next screen is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line and check it...

```
  Button  btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);<---------Remove it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       Button  btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
```

and

```
       Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
```

So you got two onClickListeners on the same button.